# PlasticSCM issue: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:8084

Tags: plasticscm

I recently created a PlasticSCM account and I am in the step of creating a new distributed Plastic Cloud repository. However, whenever I tried to create it, I encounter the following errors

No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:8084

[Window that appears when I tried to create the distributed repository](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oNwxB.png)

What can I do to proceed on this? Thanks!

Comment: If you open the Windows services panel, could you check if the "Plastic SCM Server" is up and running?

Comment: Where can I find the Window service plannel. I am currently at Workspace Explorer but can not find anything. There is still a big red "Cannot connect to the Plastic SCM server. Retrying in 40 seconds" warning in the red bar.

Comment: https://www.thewindowsclub.com/open-windows-services

Answer (score 0):

I got this same issue **in Unity** when I tried to remove the Organization name from the autofilled Repository name.

1. The Repository Name field defaulted to:
   Project@OrganizationName@cloud
2. I changed it to: PROJECT. That's when I got the error message
3. **Updating only the project name and leaving the original autofilled part with "OrganizationName" and "cloud" solved the problem for me: New-Project-Name@OrganizationName@cloud**

By default, any changes to the Repository Field also updates the Workspace Name.

Found some information later: [UNITY PLASTIC SCM Setup Guide](https://unity.com/support-services/redeem/plastic-scm) under "Create a workspace and repo" (hidden in navigation further down the page)